# JMX client accessible locally only

Tags: java, jmx

I want to create a JMX agent that has to be accessible from local host only.

- Please advise how can I do that.
- Also help with a Simple JMX client on same machine that will connect to that JMX agent.
- If somehow we can get away with specifying an explicit port, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevg) helpful. It uses the [attach API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/attach/index.html) for Oracle's JVM to connect to a running Java process and have it start a local only JMX agent. You would setup whatever MBeans you want to expose as usual. I get the impression that this code is similar to what JConsole does for connecting to local JVM processes. You might also want to investigate the source for [Jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm) which leverages JConsole for connecting to local JVM processes.

Comment: The one advisory about using the attach API is that under the covers, it basically spins up a javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer which it then uses to provide you a JMXConnection and MBeanServerConnection. Whether or not that RMIConnectorServer is accessible from another host is dependent on a host (he he) of variables. In my experience, Windows yes, *nix no.