# Finding out Java options used by Java application

Tags: java, parameters, config

Is there any way where I can find out which Java options are being used by a Java application inside JVM (e.g. the ones passed through the command line)?

I want to find it on the fly when the application is running, but from outside outside the application.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JMX:

```
final JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(connectorAddress));
final MBeanServerConnection mBeanServerConnection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
final ObjectName commandLine = new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Runtime");
final List<Attribute> arguments = mBeanServerConnection.getAttributes(commandLine, new String[] {"InputArguments"}).asList();
String[] inputArguments = (String[]) arguments.get(0).getValue();
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(inputArguments));
connector.close();
```

To get the JMX connection, you might find my answer to " [JMX client accessible locally only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629667/jmx-client-accessible-locally-only/6632617#6632617) " helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
    System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to know if its possible from outside of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use JMX. It allows to get options, properties, etc. from inside as well as outside of application.

[image: jmx]

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Java does not support the "INTERCEPTING" of method arguments, method args are not logged or intercepted in the JVM .

**However, you can easily print out the args sent to a running class using the System.env example in the other answer on this thread .**

HOWEVER, if you have control over the actual applications source code, you can follow the directions here : [How do I intercept a method invocation with standard java features (no AspectJ etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576918/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-invocation-with-standard-java-features-no-aspectj-e)

This will allow you to log and intercept the args being sent to the main method.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking, the poster wants the JVM args, not the args of any particular method.